# Segue between two SKScenes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, viewcontroller, skscene

I have two different ViewControllers that get there scenes from two SKScene classes. I need to segue from my MainMenu SKScene to my GameScene SKScene when i touch the MainMenu scene. I also set up two storyboards in the main.storybaord. Each sotryboard is set to the correct ViewControllers

Comment: Sounds like you are over complexing your code here,  Is 2 storyboards really needed inside of another storyboard?  Anyway, to properly segue between 2 storyboards using SKScenes, you want to create delegation methods for your view controller. See http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/01/swift-swift-using-segues-and-delegates-in-navigation-controllers-part-1-the-template/ for an example on how to do it.  (I know it says navigation controller, but the idea behind it still works)